# jQuery Intellisense: Common reference file (stdafx) for vsdoc

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense, vsdoc

I moved the jQuery in my project over to Microsoft's CDN yesterday so finally have jQuery intellisense back. Yay!  However, I apparently need to include the following in all my .js files:

```
//These references should enable intellisense within this file
///<reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.js" />
///<reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" />
```

I would prefer to have a single js file which contains the above references such that I have a single, unchanging reference in all my js files like so:

```
//These references should enable intellisense within this file
///<reference path="/shared/js/stdafx.js" />
```

The idea is that stdafx.js would be the file containing the jQuery references.  Then I have only *one* place to update the versions or add additional references.  I gave it a quick go, but it didn't seem to work.  Can anyone figure out a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the above common reference did work in the end.  I didn't realize how quirky VS was in regards to js intellisense.  Funny enough it kicked in after compiling the project.

I did try Ctrl-Shift-J which refreshes the JavaScript as well.  It takes a few seconds for it to kick in so give it a chance.  Another tip I read was dragging the common.js file into the editor of the .js file I wanted to add the common reference to.  This sanity check ensured I had the correct path (it did).  It added a relative path (../shared/stdafx.js) but I was able to use an absolute path (/shared/js/stdafx.js) which means I can modify the VS .js template for new js files.

So I would suggest anyone who comes across this question to persevere, refresh the JavaScript, compile, even close and reopen VS as it will hopefully kick in for you eventually.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wanting jQuery intellisense in their .js files (and why wouldn't you) you need to 'reference' the correct jQuery VSDOC file, that MS created for Visual Studio intellisense:

///<reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js" />

To test it, type:

$(

You should see full intellisense with PARAMETERS, as well as members. If you only see a single list of members, it's not working.